# Android - SurfaceTexture.updateTexImage and MediaPlayer

Tags: android, video, opengl-es, android-mediaplayer

I play a video with mediaPlayer and modify it using surfaceTexture and OpenGL ES 2.0.

In the doc, it says that

```
surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
```

will "update the texture image to the most recent frame from the image stream".

So if I call 2 times updateTexImage, the texture image will not necessarily be the 2nd frame of the video ?

If this is the case, then I guess there is no way to control the speed of the video with media player and OpenGL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you call 2 times updateTexImage, it may not be 2nd frame of the video.
There is no way you can fasten the (increase fps) video than input. However, with timing of updateTexImage, you can slow down (reduced fps), skipping frames.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I guess MediaPlayer is not an option to decode videos frame by frame..